# A way of saying "What could have been"

Tags: terminology

What's another way of saying "what could/should have been?"

Ex. She reminisced of what could have been.

Preferably short

Comment: She *pondered* what could have been? She *lamented* what could/should have been? She *mulled over* what could have been? She *ruminated* on what might have been?

Comment: might-have-been, in her dreams

Comment: It's no shorter, but native speakers are almost infinitely more likely to say *She reminisced **on** (or **over**) what could have been.*

Comment: @user284985 She reminisced over what had been wasted

Comment: missed opportunity?